# How does menu in linux works?

Tags: c++, linux, x11, dbus, xlib

I would like to know how linux handles applications window menus. I am working on a panel application, but for starters I want to list menu items of currently focused window. Where should I start my research?
Thanks

**TLDR (answer)**: in linux, every window handles its own menu. No centralized menu like in eg. OS X.

**Edit:** okay, thanks for your insights even though my question was quite broad. I now understand that in linux there isn't a centralized way to do window menus, but every window handles its own menu. That means there is no bullet proof way to do global menu (although Unity has a good implementation).
Anyway, I decided to start digging around Qt and [appmenu-qt5](https://launchpad.net/appmenu-qt5).

Comment: google is a good place to start a research

Comment: i did, bud didn't find anything I could use..

Comment: I'm not even close to believing you :p first learn about window managers, then x-server, then you will be closer to googling the right thing

Comment: Linux has no "menu", you're going to have to pick a specific window manager.

Comment: okay, so let's assume xfwm4

Comment: Window managers are only responsible for the title bar and borders around an application's window.  Everything *within* the window, including things like toolbars and menu bars, are created by the application itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few attempts to get a global menu bar, which partially faces the same problem: a global menu bar cannot possibly work if the global menu bar cannot determine which menus the window contains. This has required patches to GTK+, to Qt, and to various applications, and not all of those patches have been accepted.

If you're interested, you can make sure your system does include all those patches, and then you can use the same interface as that used by the global menu bar. (Most designs make the global menu bar optional; you won't be required to use the global menu bar just to access that interface.)

Not all attempts to get a global menu bar have used the same approach with the same patches. The most recent attempt, I believe, has been by Ubuntu, but their approach is not compatible with earlier approaches such as the gnome2-globalmenu project. Ubuntu's patches are freely available, or for simplicity, you might develop on an Ubuntu system.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know how linux handles applications window menus...I want to list menu items of currently focused window

1. The desktop GUI on GNU/Linux systems is heterogeneous at this level.  Most applications will implement menus using a widget toolkit, commonly GTK+, but there is no guarantee of that.
2. There is no requirement or standard methodology to report menu options externally.  They are part of a process's private memory.

In short, you can dig around about this as much as you want, you will not find anything.  Individual window managers/desktop environments will not have implemented anything to facilitate it because, as per #2 above, most individual applications will not have either, and if a WM *required* this, it'd be excluding practically everything.

Comment: An application's (or toolkit's) accessibility support *might* be a possibility:  if a screenreader can get the names of the menu items, so can another program.  I don't know anything about the interfaces for this, though.

Answer (score 0):

Read about [X11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11), [X Window System core protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System_core_protocol), [window managers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager), [ICCCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-Client_Communication_Conventions_Manual), and [EWMH](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-1.3.html)

Then you'll realize that you should use some existing C++ graphical [toolkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_toolkits). Probably [Qt](http://qt-project.org/), but you might try [Fox Toolkit](http://www.fox-toolkit.org/) also (or [GtkMM](http://www.gtkmm.org/en/)...)

Life is too short to do all that by yourself (without using a toolkit, but by coding directly for [Xlib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xlib)). By the time (several years) you'll get something, [wayland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_%28display_server_protocol%29) might be relevant to replace X11.

See also [libsdl](http://www.libsdl.org/).

Notice that the window manager (and the application) could customize the menu ....